# Copy Pasting Range of different length using VBA

Tags: vba, loops, range, copy-paste

https://i.stack.imgur.com/93bt7.png

Hi,

I am trying to work with a code I have made but am having some trouble.

If you look at my photo above, in cell B3 I have a CUSIP. What I want to do is copy that CUSIP and paste it in each row of info for that CUSIP (so rows A4 till A8). Then I want to move to the second CUSIP in J3 (the CUSIPS are all in row 3 and 8 columns apart) and then paste the CUSIP in rows J4 to J35.

I want to keep doing this over and over for 1000 securities but the issue is that the rows differ in length.

My code is working until I get to the last piece of code which I have put in as a comment. It works but is static. Only works for moving from the 1st to 2nd security then fails. I am trying to think of a dynamic way for me to move from the cell which the CUSIP is last pasted in to the third row and corresponding column everytime (column will be 9 apart every time from the last pasted cell).

Here it is:

```
Sub CUSIP_Copy_Paste()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim r As Long

Range("B3").Select

    LastCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

For c = 2 To LastCol Step 8

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).row

        ActiveCell.Copy

        Cells(4, ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

For r = 5 To LastRow

    Cells(r, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next r

     ''''''ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 9).Select

Next c

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in the final offset. Instead of -5, put in a variable, preferrably the variable which is the difference between the end of the rows count and the beginning, which is always 3.

That is to say, Offset(3 - lastRow, 9)

You almost had it friendo :)

Comment: I'm  having another issue you might be able to help with, I have three separate macros that I want to combine into one macro by calling each one. In addition, I want there to be pauses between each before running (there is BBRG data I want to fully refresh). However, it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Sub RunAll()

Call ClearContents_RefreshSheet

               Application.Wait (Now + ("00:01:30"))

Call CUSIP_Copy_Paste

                 Application.Wait (Now + ("00:00:05"))

Call Copy_Pastee_Data_Into_Vertical_Format

End Sub

Comment: I am not sure if you posted it entirely or if you edited parts, but the correct syntax is (Now() + timevalue("00:00:005")) as opposed to Now + ("00:00:05")